# Movie similar to "Fargo" where the protagonist tries to act like a thug but is just a pathetic loser

Tags: identify-this-movie, fargo

The whole atmosphere of the movie is similar to "Fargo".

It happens in a small town. It's a story about a loser who tries to act like a thug. But he is just a pathetic loser.

While he is trying to look bad, a guy in the bar **mocks him by throwing darts at him (points to his winter jacket)**. That causes the first guy to try to poison this mocker with motor (or brake) oil he would slip in the water system in his yard. But the dude dies from food poisoning, and this guy still wants to take credit for his death, just to prove himself as tough and dangerous.

In the shop he meets his friend who is mentally challenged, and later tries to fake a kidnapping (not so sure about that).

The sister of that friend runs a garage rental firm, which their father left them.

At the end, police surround them at the gas station (they are inside the store), and he intentionally admits something that he did not do (maybe killing a cop, and runs from the police into the woods. (Not sure if he was in a vehicle or not.) The police shoot him, but the legend says they never found his body.

This is all I can remember about this movie. Hope I was not too confusing, and thanks to anyone who can answer this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's the 2006 comedy [Live Free or Die](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_Free_or_Die_(2006_film)) with Aaron Stanford, Paul Schneider and Zooey Deschanel.

> A clueless, aspiring criminal named John "Rugged" Rudgate (Stanford) spends his days forging rebate coupons and selling speakers out the back of his van. One day, Rugged runs into an old acquaintance, the dim-witted Jeff Lagrand (Schneider), who recently returned home to help his cynical sister run the storage facility that they inherited from their father. When Rugged tries to force his way into the Lagrand family business, things go terribly wrong—and the situation gets even more complicated when an emotionally unstable cop begins investigating.

Everything you described is there (the brake oil revenge, the gas station surrounded by cops, etc). Here's the trailer:

Comment: Thank you a million times! Did not sleep for three days because of this!